# jQuery mega menu hoverIntent mouseOut

Tags: jquery, hoverintent, megamenu

I'm using Soh Tanaka's "Mega Menu" - http://www.sohtanaka.com/web-design/mega-drop-downs-w-css-jquery/ - on a dropdown menu and having some issues with the "out" function. The menu uses hoverIntent and should fade out with a timeout delay of "500", but it just disappears on mouseout:

http://native.thefutureforward.com/

The JS file in question is "js/mega-menu.min.js". I realize my code is a bit messy at the moment, so I'm working on that.

Any help on getting the mouseOut of the menu to both delay and fade out would be much appreciated!

Comment: Do you have a live page that we can preview?   In megaHoverOver, $(this).find(".sub").stop().fadeTo('fast', 1).show(); is supposed to fade the menu in and in megaHoveOut, $(this).find(".sub").stop().fadeTo('fast', 0, function () { $(this).hide();}); will fade out the menu.  The durations are part of the menuconfig you pass to the HI plugin.

Comment: Yea, everything is basically set to the defaults from the tutorial. I've linked to my page in my post above, but here it is again - http://native.thefutureforward.com/. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Your code is a bit different from what I pulled from the demo when I built my menus:

```
 //Set custom configurations
 var menuConfig = {
     sensitivity: 2, // number = sensitivity threshold (must be 1 or higher)
     interval: 100, // number = milliseconds for onMouseOver polling interval
     over: megaHoverOver, // function = onMouseOver callback (REQUIRED)
     timeout: 500, // number = milliseconds delay before onMouseOut
     out: megaHoverOut // function = onMouseOut callback (REQUIRED)
 };


 $(document).ready(function () {
      $("ul#topnav li .sub").css({ 'opacity': '0' }); 
      $("ul#topnav li").hoverIntent(menuConfig); 
 });
```

Notice that I pass the config to the hoverIntent, not the function names.

Comment: That looks pretty similar to mine...am I missing something? `code:  var config = {    
   sensitivity: 2, // number = sensitivity threshold (must be 1 or higher)    
   interval: 100, // number = milliseconds for onMouseOver polling interval    
   over: megaHoverOver, // function = onMouseOver callback (REQUIRED)    
   timeout: 500, // number = milliseconds delay before onMouseOut    
   out: megaHoverOut // function = onMouseOut callback (REQUIRED)    
 };

 $(document).ready(function () {
  $("ul#topnav li .sub").css({'opacity':'0'});
  $("ul#topnav li").hoverIntent(config);
 });`

Comment: I was looking at the Buy button, that was my mistake. My JS file is the following: http://cma.velabusinesssolutions.com/scripts/cma.menu.js and it's slightly different than yours. I made some modifications to how the functions were defined and I also modified how the width calculations are done so i could adjust the left position of the menu if it flowed outside of the parent container.

Comment: So weird..I tried adding in a couple of your adjustments, and then I tried just using your code entirely, all to no avail. On mouse out refuses to delay or fadeout...it just instantly disappears...

Comment: Ugh. This is driving me nuts. Any other ideas?

Comment: @nickff Did you ever figure out the reason behind this? I'm running into a similar problem.